# Are there localized versions of help.ubuntu.com?

Tags: language-support, documentation, translation

Quando a documentação oficial do ubuntu sera traduzida para o Português?

When will there be an official documentation of Ubuntu, that is translated into Portuguese?

Comment: mas a gente ajuda no que puder, mesmo se os artigos não estiverem traduzidos. o fórum de portugal é bem bom, mas desatualizado. se precisares, eu dou uma procurada e te ajudo com os tópicos. abraços

Answer (score 1):

The translation into Brazilian Portuguese is pretty well covered, while the translation into Portuguese as spoken in Portugal is less so. You may want to ask the question to respective team of translators:

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-l10n-pt

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-l10n-pt-br