# (un)localize help.ubuntu.com

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, locale, localization, ubuntu-wiki

I often help people here on Ask or on other international websites.
In order to do so, sometimes I have to refer to the great guides on http://help.ubuntu.com .

Problem is, my system is localized (in Italian) and I can only see Italian webpages there, for example [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/mouse-mousekeys.html) has [this output for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt1nB.png), and you can see that it is in Italian.

Now, I never said that I would like to have that page - or any other on the portal - localized (usually localized pages lack a lot of informations, or they are older and not suitable for the purpose anymore).

How can I access (and then divulge) the unlocalized version of it?
Is there a way to pass to the page that I want it in the original version?
I already tried to append various combinations of `?ln=en` and similar to the URL, but with no success.

If not, how can I mimic an unlocalized version of my system through my browser (I mainly use Google Chrome)?
Is there any parameter that I can change in the browsers (Chrome, Chromium Firefox) in order to unlocalize these webpages?

---

I'm not entirely sure it this question belongs here, since it is a bit more about a problem with the website than with Ubuntu itself, but at least you can help me find the correct place where to place it, since it definitely does not go on Meta.
Or we can try to cook up a local workaround for the problem.

---

There is already a [similar (mirror) version of the problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/6789/29595), in which somebody asks when a Portuguese version of the help would come out.
**Please note** that I want the opposite! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a browser setting, and at some point you did say that you preferred multilingual web pages to be displayed in Italian. ;)

In Google Chrome, go to Settings (advanced), where you will find an interface for changing the language settings.